# Laravel post route with parameters

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, routes

Im trying to do a post request via a form in my blade template with a parameter in the url . 
Here is my form:

```
<form action="/products/{{$produit->id}}" method="post">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" name="avis_body" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Here is my web.php:

```
Route::post('/products/{$id}', function($id){
    return $id;
});
```

I don't know what im doing wrong. Im receiving this error:
[image]

Comment: typo `{{$produit->id}}` ? check if it is `null`

Comment: no it is not null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `$` from route declaration:

```
Route::post('/products/{id}', function($id){
    return $id;
});
```